WebpackObfuscator produces JS file that's twice the size
I am bundling ES6 modules for the browser using Webpack, and I've found that if I use either WebpackObfuscator or JavaScriptObfuscator, my bundle JS file is about twice the size (and much larger than I'd like for the browser).
Without WebpackObfuscator:
webpack --mode production --progress

asset app.js 204 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset 513.app.js 28.6 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (id hint: vendors)
asset 25.app.js 22.6 KiB [emitted] [minimized]

(main app.js is 204 KiB)
With WebpackObfuscator:
webpack --mode production --progress

asset app.js 480 KiB [emitted] [minimized] [big] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset 513.app.js 67.2 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (id hint: vendors)
asset 25.app.js 51.2 KiB [emitted] [minimized]

(main app.js is 480 KiB!)
All files produced are twice the size with obfuscation than without.
Is this expected?
My webpack.config.js looks like this:
import path from 'path';
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
import WebpackObfuscator from 'webpack-obfuscator';

// __dirname doesn't work with ES6 modules :/
// https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-dirname-is-not-defined-in-es-module-scope
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js',
    library: "app",
    clean: true
  },
  target: ["web", "es2020"],
  plugins: [
    new WebpackObfuscator({
      rotateStringArray: true
    })
  ]
};

Anyone know of a less bloaty JS obfuscator for webpack?
